# Tkinter List of Variable Sizes

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter, menu

I'm trying to make a menu of buttons using Tkinter. I have a randomly generated list of files with their attributes as tuples (Name, Size, Link), and need to arrange them in a grid. I can't set each button to the grid since the number of buttons changes. Here is how I tried to make it:

```
    def selected_button(file):
        print(f"File: {file[0]}, {file[1]}, Link: {file[2]}")

    for file in files:
        fileButton = Button(root, text= file[0],command= lambda: selected_button(file).grid()`
```

Problems:

- The variable "file" that gets passed on at the button click is always the last generated button's.
- The buttons arrange themselves as a long list in one column - I need a nice square/rectangle.

If I left out any info, comment and I'll answer promptly.

Comment: _"I can't set each button to the grid since the number of buttons changes."_ that doesn't make much sense. There's nothing in tkinter to prevent you from doing that. Also, you say you need a "nice square/rectangle". If that's they case, why are  you using no arguments to `grid`? It lets you specify both the row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1

To get the `lambda` to store the current value in the iteration it needs to be called out in the lambda function such as `command= lambda f = file: selected_button(f)`.

Problem #2

The method I would usually use for making a grid of buttons is pick a width you want, possibly 3 wide, then increment the column until it reaches that point. Once that width is reached, reset the column and increment the row.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Testing
files = []
for x in range(12):
    files.append((f"Test{x}", f"stuff{x}", f"other{x}"))
# /Testing

def selected_button(file):
    print(f"File: {file[0]}, {file[1]}, Link: {file[2]}")

root = tk.Tk()

r, c = (0,0) # Set the row and column to 0.

c_limit = 3 # Set a limit for how wide the buttons should go.

for file in files:
    tk.Button(root,
              text= file[0],
              width = 20,
              # This will store what is currently in file to f
              # then assign it to the button command.
              command= lambda f=file: selected_button(f)
              ).grid(row = r, column = c)

    c += 1 # increment the column by 1
    if c == c_limit:
        c = 0 # reset the column to 0
        r += 1 # increment the row by 1

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example]